# How do I update the click handler so that it will cycle through three colors: red, green, and blue?

Tags: java, swing, colors

So the purpose of this program is to create an ellipse and a button that when you click on it, the ellipse will change color. The order of the colors should go red, then green and then blue. How do I create this cycle? Do I use a for loop? This is my code without the cycle:

```
public class ButtonButton implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{

   private NscWindow win;
   private NscEllipse oval;

   public ButtonButton() {
     win = new NscWindow();
     win.setTitle("ButtonButton");
     oval = new NscEllipse(100, 70, 200, 150);
     oval.setFilled(true);
     oval.setBackground(java.awt.Color.blue);

     javax.swing.JButton btn;
     btn = new javax.swing.JButton("click me");
     win.add(oval);
     btn.setSize(170, 35);
     btn.setLocation(110, 10);
     win.add(btn);
     win.repaint();
     btn.addActionListener(this);

  }
   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
     win.setTitle("Thanks, I needed that");
     javax.swing.JButton btn;
     btn = (javax.swing.JButton)e.getSource();
     btn.setText("Thanks, I needed that");
     oval.setBackground(java.awt.Color.green);
     win.repaint();
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonButton();
 }
}
```

Comment: You want to change colors on each click or after a short delay?

Comment: Each click. The idea is that every time you click the button it goes trough the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cycle through each, do something like this:

```
 public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
     win.setTitle("Thanks, I needed that");
     javax.swing.JButton btn;
     btn = (javax.swing.JButton)e.getSource();
     btn.setText("Thanks, I needed that");

     if (oval.getBackground().equals(java.awt.Color.red))
         oval.setBackground(java.awt.Color.green);
     else if (oval.getBackground().equals(java.awt.Color.green))
         oval.setBackground(java.awt.Color.blue);
     else if (oval.getBackground().equals(java.awt.Color.blue))
         oval.setBackground(java.awt.Color.red);
     win.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, and if I answered your question please mark as resolved by clicking the opaque check mark next to the answer for other devs on the forum

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating an array of your colors...

```
public static final Color COLORS[] = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};
```

Provide some kind of value to track which color your up to...

```
private int colorIndex = -1;
```

Add a convience method to change the color...

```
public void applyNextColor() {
    colorIndex++;
    if (colorIndex >= COLORS.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    oval.setBackground(COLORS[colorIndex]);
}
```

Then in your constructor initialise the initial color...

```
public ButtonButton() {
    win = new NscWindow();
    win.setTitle("ButtonButton");
    oval = new NscEllipse(100, 70, 200, 150);
    oval.setFilled(true);
    nextColor();

    //...
}
```

Then in you action listener, simply apply the next color...

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    win.setTitle("Thanks, I needed that");
    // This is a NullPointerException waiting to happen...
    //javax.swing.JButton btn;
    btn = (javax.swing.JButton)e.getSource();
    btn.setText("Thanks, I needed that");
    applyNextColor();
    win.repaint();
}
```

You could do the same thing with `enum` and/or modular maths, but this keeps it simple ;)